# Deinterlace and convert frame rate keeping all frames with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a video that is interlaced and has a frame rate of 30000/1001.
If I deinterlace it using bwdif, and keeping one output frame per field, I get a fps of 60000/1001, as expected.

I want to convert this video to 50 fps keeping all frames, and thus slowing it a bit down.

If I do it with two ffmpeg commands, like the following, it works:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex bwdif test.mp4
ffmpeg -i test.mp4  -filter_complex "[v1]setpts=60000/1001/50*PTS[v2];[v2]fps=50" test2.mp4
```

I would like to do it in one command. I tried the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0]bwdif[v1];[v1]setpts=60000/1001/50*PTS[v2];[v2]fps=50" test.mp4
```

However, the result does not look as expected: some frames are duplicated and others are dropped.

Does anybody know why this is? Is there a correct way to do it in one command?

Comment: A couple things you can try. (1) Reverse the math and set input `-r`  option so the deinterlaced video is in the desired frame rate OR (2) use `-vsync 0` option and `-r 50` output option so it will not mess with frames.

Comment: Thanks! First option works if i remove the setpts and fps filters; while the second has the drawback to output a video with a variable frame rate, which is not what I want. What also works is to remove the fps filter and replace it with a -r 50 output option (-vsync 0 does not seem necessary)